# Xenserver 6.5 LSI MegaRAID

Tags: xenserver, lsi, megaraid, megacli

Is there a package available to install the MegaCLI on XenServer6.5? For 6.5 there is this [1] but 6.5 has another kernel. XenServer 6.5 is based on CentOS6.5 (right?), so I also tried the `kmod-megaraid_sas-06.806.08.00_el6.5-1.x86_64.rpm` but that's also not fitting. Are there other sources I can try?

[1] http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX141458

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new version of the MegaCli: storCli. You can get it from here: http://www.lsi.com/support/pages/download-results.aspx?keyword=storcli

In that archive is a Linux folder and you can install the package with `rpm -ivh storcli-1.14.12-1.noarch.rpm`. After that, you have a `storcli64` in /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/

Works fine with XenServer 6.5.

Comment: The LSI download mirrors are down. You can get it from the SuperMicro site instead ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/Driver/SAS/LSI/Tools/storcli_6.6-1.14.12/Linux/

Comment: Here's the StorCLI command reference: http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/12352476