# Where to get storcli64 for Linux from LSI MegaRAID now that Broadcom has taken over?

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, lsi, megaraid

I need the Linux shell interface, `storcli64` for the Dell PERC H700 (aka LSI MegaRAID) as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/589070/how-to-monitor-the-hard-disk-status-behind-dell-perc-h710-raid-controller-with-c#comment951595_589166) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/681194), but the download links all appear to be defunct.

How can I get the appropriate files now for Linux (specifically Proxmox 6.1 with Debian Buster underpinning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the hwraid.le-vert.net repo's as it's easier to keep a deployment up to date using package repositories.

This guide will work for you https://chiranjeevigk.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/install-lsi-megariad-storage-manger-on-proxmox/

Note: Proxmox has no built in RAID monitoring, so short of the card beeping you'll need to configure something to monitor your raid health such as netdata or prometheus exporter.

Answer (score 4):

```
Start on the broadcom Homepage: www.broadcom.com
Click on Support -> MegaRAID and HBAs
Then Support Documents and Downloads
Fill out the Form:
- Product Group: Storage Adapters
- Product Family: Raid Controller Cards
- Product Name: Select a Megaraid Adapter (e.g. MegaRaid 9440-8i)
Click on Search

Expand Management Software and Tools
Download: Latest MegaRAID StorCLI
```

Comment: For any old/oldish MegaRAID, `storcli2` won''t work as the controller isn''t supported. I cannot seem to find `storcli64` anywhere.