# How do I reconfigure my disk array on a Dell machine under Linux?

Tags: linux, raid, dell-perc

I have a Dell R620 with a PERC RAID controller (`lspci` shows "RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)").

I had placed a single disk in it, made it a "RAID0" raid level logical disk (which is a stripe with only one stripe). I put a filesystem on it, used it- but I always intended to mirror it.

Fast forward a month, and I now have a second disk. How do I add this disk and magically create a RAID1 (mirrored) array from my RAID0 array?

Prefer not to have to bring down my system.

Answer (score 2):

This is for CentOS 7, but similar actions can be performed on other Linux versions I'm sure (left as an exercise for the reader):

Put your new disk in the system (presuming it's hot-swappable. If not, you shouldn't be here).

Set up the Dell OMSA repo; create `/etc/yum.repos.d/dell-omsa-repository.repo`:

`[dell-omsa-indep]
name=Dell OMSA repository - Hardware independent
type=rpm-md
mirrorlist=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/mirrors.cgi?osname=el$releasever&basearch=$basearch
&native=1&dellsysidpluginver=$dellsysidpluginver
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/RPM-GPG-KEY-dell
    http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/RPM-GPG-KEY-libsmbios
enabled=1
failover=priority
bootstrapurl=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi`

[dell-omsa-specific]
name=Dell OMSA repository - Hardware specific
type=rpm-md
mirrorlist=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/mirrors.cgi?osname=el$releasever&basearch=$basearch
&native=1&sys_ven_id=$sys_ven_id&sys_dev_id=$sys_dev_id&dellsysidpluginver=$dellsysidpluginver
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/RPM-GPG-KEY-dell
    http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/RPM-GPG-KEY-libsmbios
enabled=1
failover=priority
bootstrapurl=http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi

Do: `yum cleanall; yum make cache`
Install the `srvadmin-omacore` package, and whatever packages it wants with it.

Study your system; again Your Mileage May Vary:

Show all controllers:
`omreport storage controller`

Show all Virtual (Logical) disks:
`omreport storage vdisk`

Show all physical disks on controller 0:
`omreport storage pdisk controller=0`

Show all logical disks on controller 0:
`omreport storage vdisk controller=0`

Show all physical disks on vdisk with ID 1:
`omreport storage pdisk controller=0 vdisk=1`

Now assuming your RAID (aka Virtual Disk) is on Controller 0, and assuming its ID is 1, and assuming your physical disks have IDs of `0:0:2` and `0:0:3`, do this:

`omconfig storage vdisk action=reconfigure controller=0 vdisk=1 raid=r1 pdisk=0:0:2,0:0:3`

The process took over 24 hours for me, for 1TB 2.5" SAS drives. Much of that time, `omreport` continued to call the array "RAID0" until it had finished the reconfiguration. Then it had to make another housekeeping pass which took about an hour or two.