# Using Dell Omreport on Dell attached storage

Tags: ubuntu, storage, dell, network-attached-storage, dell-powervault

Hi I have a Dell Powervault 1220 mounted to a PERC H800 (/dev/sda)

I'm really confused on how to use dells monitoring software, srvadmin.

According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/589070/how-to-monitor-the-hard-disk-status-behind-dell-perc-h710-raid-controller-with-c), I should use omreport.

However, what is the controller id I'm looking for?

```
/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin/omreport storage pdisk -?
pdisk            Display physical disk(s) properties.

Required parameters are:
controller=id               All physical disks are displayed

Optional parameters are:
vdisk=id                    All physical disks that comprise the indicated
                            virtual disk
cachecade=id            All physical disks that comprise the indicated
                            cachecade(s)
connector=id                  All physical disks on the indicated connector
pdisk=<PDISKID>               The indicated physical disk
    where PDISKID=<connector:enclosureID:portID | connector:targetID>
```

Also, I'm using ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 0):

To get the controller ID you use the controller option:

```
omreport storage controller
```

Depending how many controllers in your system you may get a number of results back, to narrow it down look at the Name of the controller:

```
omreport storage controller | grep "ID\|Name"
ID                                            : 0
Name                                          : PERC 6/i Integrated
```

This system only has a single controller so the controller ID to use is 0:

```
omreport storage pdisk controller=0
omreport storage vdisk controller=0
```