# Local File Copy Incredibly Slow

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge, xcopy

I have 15 Server 2008 R2 servers. On 2 of them, copying files locally is incredibly slow.

I need to make copies of a 2GB folder which has 8000 files in it. On 13 servers, a simple xcopy command has this done in minutes. On the other 2, it has taken hours. Stopped/restarted. No difference. Single files that are 5-10k take about a minute each. Have tried copy/paste. Same speed.

Servers are Poweredge T320. 16GB RAM. The files are being copied on a pair of mirrored drives. Plenty of resources available as this is a simple file server for an office of 10 people.

Comment: Did you try to restart the server? If so, it is possible that one of the mirrored drive is failing. Please post the disk's S.M.A.R.T. data (you can use [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) or [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org))

Comment: Yes, they've been rebooted. Dell Server Manager does not report any failed/failing drives (this issue first arose months ago but was never followed up with). SMART not unavailable. Getting the same info from smartmontools as posted here : https://serverfault.com/questions/589070/how-to-monitor-the-hard-disk-status-behind-dell-perc-h710-raid-controller-with-c

Comment: What are the perfmon numbers (disk access times, network load, RAM, swap usage) on these two servers as opposed to the other 13?  I'm with @shodanshok in thinking your mirror is about to die, but there may be other factors here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/J0A1y - Screenshot of disk usage. Perfmon is the same across all servers. Very, very little usage as these are simply file/print server for small branches.

Comment: @user697508 so, did you get SMART data? Can you post the exact disks model? Is the write cache enabled or disabled? Reading from files without writing anything (ie: ftp upload) is fast or slow? We really need more information to help you...